# estoy haciendo una vista para que el admin tenga acceso a todo pero tengo este error

Tags: php

> Warning: Undefined variable $conexion in C:\xampp\htdocs\MedicInven\Plantillas\header.php on line 16
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\MedicInven\Plantillas\funciones.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\MedicInven\Plantillas\header.php(16): obtenerRolUsuario(NULL) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\MedicInven\index.php(1): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\MedicInven\Plantillas\funciones.php on line 6

Comment: No has seteado la variable `$conexion`